# What are the values to be passed for the parameters in the request body of Azure Devops Rest API Create Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I want to automate process of creating build, releases in azure devops. So I'm trying to use the azure devops rest API create pipeline. But the microsoft documentation does not clearly explain the use of the parameters in the request body and the values to be passed .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#configurationtype

"configuration": {
"type": {
"designerHyphenJson": ,
"designerJson": ,
"justInTime": ,
"yaml":
}
}

Can anyone let me know what are the values to be given for the above types in the configuration object.